# Twitter Bootstrap - Making CSS Icons bigger

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and it says to use `<i class="icon-flag"></i>` if I want to use an icon from their CSS sprite.

How can I add my own css class called `.logo-icon` which will take one of their icons but make it bigger?

My class currently looks like:

```
.logo-icon {
    background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
    background-position: -312px -24px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not going to look as nice as using FontAwesome (which is an actual font), but you can scale glyphicons using the **background-size** property.  This will also entail scaling all the other values by an identical factor, which means you can't just do this generally, but will need to do this for a single icon at a time.

Example, doubling the flag icon would be:

```
.icon-flag.logo-icon {
  width: 28px;  // 14px * 2
  height: 28px; // 14px * 2
  background-size: 938px 318px;  // original dimensions * 2
  background-position: -624px -48px;  // original position * 2
}
```

If you do want to do this for arbitrary icons, you would be better off working with the LESS where you could probably generate this programatically.  Personally, I think switching to FontAwesome is the better alternative.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do it for a logo. I've not heard of FontAwesome? How does FontAwesome work and is it a better way of having a logo icon?

Comment: Background-size does the trick but FontAwesome is a brilliant solution! Thanks for the fantastic answer! A+

Comment: @Jamesking56 Be wary of using FontAwesome if you're going for mobile and are trying to fit within a 1 second page load time.  Browsers tend not to start displaying anything until they've got all the fonts loaded.  You probably wouldn't notice anything at all on a desktop but over a mobile network this could make your site unpleasant until the font is cached.

Comment: @GilesRoberts [FontAwesome officially recommends using the version hosted by BootstrapCDN](http://blog.fontawesome.io/2013/05/20/get-the-most-out-font-awesome-and-bootstrapcdn/), which should significantly improve your chances of the font (in addition to the CSS) being cached already, even for new visitors.

Comment: @Jamesking56 Ah interesting.  Do you have figures on how this affects cache hit ratios?  I'm still working on 20% of page requests are uncached, which means I've told my designer that FontAwesome is a no no for mobile.

Comment: @GilesRoberts You could dig through [the BootstrapCDN Stats](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/stats.html?v=07052013180533), which report that FontAwesome has been requested over 50,000,000 times.  However, I think a large variability factor is whether your site has a target audience which (predictably) visits other sites that use FontAwesome. I wouldn't know where to direct you for that.  Another obvious thing would be if a major site was using it, but again, I don't have that. You can always try tweeting [JDorfman](https://twitter.com/jdorfman) for more questions.

Answer (score 44):

## best and easiest

is to change font size of the `span` tag

```
span.glyphicon {
    font-size: 8px;  
}
```

or

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" style="font-size: 1.2em"></span>
```

### using FontAwesome?

And if like me you use FontAwesome too, you could go **hybrid** ;)
use these classes

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check fa-lg"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check fa-2x"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check fa-3x"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check fa-4x"></span>
```

Comment: best solution - use fontAwesome :)

Answer (score 14):

What if you use scale()???

```
.logo-icon {
    transform:scale(2.0,2.0);
    -ms-transform:scale(2.0,2.0); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(2.0,2.0); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(2.0,2.0); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(2.0,2.0); /* Opera */
}
```

Isn't it easier to use and maintain? You can scale to any size you wish without recalculating background-size and position.

I am using this for reducing the size of the icons in some parts of my system. I spent around 1 hour looking for a solution to reduce and almost forgot about scale(). So, just sharing to help others. =D

But, of course, if you make them bigger you will not get a perfect good looking icon.

Comment: +1 for such a simple solution that is also cross browser

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer to simple change the font size:

```
.large-icon {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```