# How can I successfully resize a Bootstrap 2.3.2 icon?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems to be an easy task, but I tried every thing on the web without lack.

How can I resize an [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#icons)  icon?

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

Comment: it should on it's own if you have all Bootstrap code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - Making CSS Icons bigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544114/twitter-bootstrap-making-css-icons-bigger)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adjusting the font size to the tag? Like so:

```
<i class="icon-search font-adjust></i>
```

Then in your CSS add:

```
.font-adjust {
    font-size: 24px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 2 uses one huge sprite picture for all its icons and is set as a `background-image` on html element. `font-size` will not work in this case. You have to play around with `background-size` and `background-position` values and width/height of element.

```css
.smaller {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: 2000%;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.bigger {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  background-size: 2000% !important;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.another-icon {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  background-size: 2000% !important;
  background-position: -200px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> smaller: <i class="icon-glass smaller"></i>
<br /> original:
<i class="icon-glass"></i>
<br /> bigger:
<i class="icon-glass bigger"></i>

<br /> another icon:<i class="icon-glass another-icon"></i>
```

As you can see, because it is an image it does not scale well. Consider upgrading to newer bootstrap version.

Here is that sprite sheet of icons:

```css
i {
  width:530px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  background-size: 100% !important;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="icon-glass"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with bootstrap but it would be an element in the stylesheet not html. you could also do an inline style.

```
<i class="icon-search" style="width:10px; height:10px;"></i>
```